# How to handle polymorphism with JSF2?

Tags: java, jsf, polymorphism, jsf-2, java-ee-6

I need to display/edit polymorphic entities.

My abstract class is **Person**.
My concrete classes are **PhysicalPerson** and **MoralPerson**

Each concrete class has its own custom attributes.

How can I use the appropriate display/edit (composite) component according to entity class ?

Thanks ! :)

Answer (score 4):

There is no such thing as `instanceof` in EL. You can however (ab)use [`Object#getClass()`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#getClass%28%29) and access the getters of [`Class`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html) in EL as well. Then just determine the outcome in the component's `rendered` attribute.

```xml
<h:panelGroup rendered="#{entity.class.name == 'com.example.PhysicalPerson'}">
    <p>According to Class#getName(), this is a PhysicalPerson.</p>
</h:panelGroup>
<h:panelGroup rendered="#{entity.class.simpleName == 'MoralPerson'}">
    <p>According to Class#getSimpleName(), this is a MoralPerson.</p>
</h:panelGroup>
```

A custom EL function would be more clean however. Note that the above doesn't work on Tomcat 7 and clones due to extremely restrictive restrictions of allowed propertynames in EL. Java reserved literals such as `class` are not allowed anymore. You'd need `#{entity['class'].name}` and so on instead.

Answer (score 1):

Another way is to create an abstract method in a base class, which will return you some mark of what instance you have, and implement it in your subclasses, like this:

```
public abstract class Person {

public abstract boolean isPhysical();

}

public PhysicalPerson extends Person {

public boolean isPhysical() {
     return true;
}

}
```

and then in jsf:

```
<h:panelGroup rendered="#{entity.physical}">
    <p>this is a PhysicalPerson.</p>
</h:panelGroup>
<h:panelGroup rendered="#{ not entity.physical}">
    <p>this is a Moral Person.</p>
</h:panelGroup>
```

However the class checking approach is more universal.

Comment: This would imply that you need to add a getter to the interface/abstract class everytime whenever you create a new implementation of `Person`. Not really useful.

Comment: boolean attribute can changed to any other. but i agree, not the most beatiful solution.