# javax.el.PropertyNotFoundException when submitting ui:repeat with conditionally rendered properties of different subclasses

Tags: jsf-2, polymorphism, subclass, uirepeat, rendered-attribute

In my backing-bean I have a collection of objects of different subclasses sharing a common interface. Inside the view, an `ui:repeat` iterates over this collection. Inside this loop, different properties have to be rendered depending on the concrete implementation of the interface.

I reduced the problem to the following backing bean:

```
@Named
@SessionScoped
public class DummyBean implements Serializable {
    private List<Type> objects = new ArrayList<Type>();

    public void add1() {
        objects.add(new Type1());
    }

    public void add2() {
        objects.add(new Type2());
    }

    public void remove(Type o) {
        objects.remove(o);
    }

    // Getter.
}
```

And the following `Type` implementations which are added by the methods `add1` and `add2`. They have some common properties, but they may also have different ones, such as `getType1OnlyMethod()` in below example:

```
public class Type1 implements Type {
    @Override
    public String getType() { return "1"; }

    public List<String> getType1OnlyMethod() {
        return Arrays.asList("only1", "only2");
    }

    // ...
}
```

```java
public class Type2 implements Type {
    @Override
    public String getType() { return "2"; }

    // ...
}
```

In the view I want to iterate over all objects which are stored in the `DummyBean` and display their contents. Depending on the concrete type of the object, the method which is only implemented in the class `Type1` may be called using the `rendered`-attribute for conditional rendering:

```
<h:form id="dummyForm">
  <ui:repeat value="#{dummyBean.objects}" var="_obj" >
    <h:outputText value="Type of the Object is #{_obj.type}." />
    <h:panelGroup rendered="#{_obj.type eq '1'}">
      <ui:repeat value="#{_obj.type1OnlyMethod}" var="_oneOnlyObject" varStatus="_status" >
        <h:outputText value="#{_oneOnlyObject}" />
      </ui:repeat>
    </h:panelGroup>
    <h:commandLink value="remove" action="#{dummyBean.remove(_obj)}">
      <f:ajax render="dummyForm" />
    </h:commandLink>
    <br/>
  </ui:repeat>

  <h:commandLink value="add1" action="#{dummyBean.add1}">
    <f:ajax render="dummyForm" />
  </h:commandLink>
  <br/>
  <h:commandLink value="add2" action="#{dummyBean.add2}">
    <f:ajax render="dummyForm" />
  </h:commandLink>
</h:form>
```

Using the `h:commandLink`s on the page I can add and remove `Type1` objects at will. If I add `Type2` objects, they are rendered as expected. But when I try to remove one of the `Type2` objects, I get an exception in the render-response phase (nevertheless if there are other elements in the list or not):

```
2014-03-24 15:42:46,754 SEVERE [javax.enterprise.resource.webcontainer.jsf.application] (default task-11) Error Rendering View[/transition/beginTestSite.xhtml]:
   javax.el.PropertyNotFoundException: /transition/beginTestSite.xhtml @23,96 value="#{_obj.type1OnlyMethod}": The class 'at.co.xss.Type2' does not have the property 'type1OnlyMethod'.
        at com.sun.faces.facelets.el.TagValueExpression.getValue(TagValueExpression.java:111) [jsf-impl-2.2.5-jbossorg-3.jar:]
        at com.sun.faces.facelets.component.UIRepeat.getValue(UIRepeat.java:279) [jsf-impl-2.2.5-jbossorg-3.jar:]
        at com.sun.faces.facelets.component.UIRepeat.getDataModel(UIRepeat.java:255) [jsf-impl-2.2.5-jbossorg-3.jar:]
        at com.sun.faces.facelets.component.UIRepeat.setIndex(UIRepeat.java:523) [jsf-impl-2.2.5-jbossorg-3.jar:]
        at com.sun.faces.facelets.component.UIRepeat.doVisitChildren(UIRepeat.java:790) [jsf-impl-2.2.5-jbossorg-3.jar:]
        at com.sun.faces.facelets.component.UIRepeat.visitTree(UIRepeat.java:748) [jsf-impl-2.2.5-jbossorg-3.jar:]
        at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.visitTree(UIComponent.java:1700) [jboss-jsf-api_2.2_spec-2.2.5.jar:2.2.5]
        at com.sun.faces.facelets.component.UIRepeat.visitTree(UIRepeat.java:754) [jsf-impl-2.2.5-jbossorg-3.jar:]
        at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.visitTree(UIComponent.java:1700) [jboss-jsf-api_2.2_spec-2.2.5.jar:2.2.5]
        at javax.faces.component.UIForm.visitTree(UIForm.java:371) [jboss-jsf-api_2.2_spec-2.2.5.jar:2.2.5]
        at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.visitTree(UIComponent.java:1700) [jboss-jsf-api_2.2_spec-2.2.5.jar:2.2.5]
        at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.visitTree(UIComponent.java:1700) [jboss-jsf-api_2.2_spec-2.2.5.jar:2.2.5]
        at com.sun.faces.application.view.FaceletPartialStateManagementStrategy.saveView(FaceletPartialStateManagementStrategy.java:472) [jsf-impl-2.2.5-jbossorg-3.jar:]
        at com.sun.faces.application.StateManagerImpl.saveView(StateManagerImpl.java:89) [jsf-impl-2.2.5-jbossorg-3.jar:]
        at javax.faces.application.StateManager.getViewState(StateManager.java:593) [jboss-jsf-api_2.2_spec-2.2.5.jar:2.2.5]
        at com.sun.faces.context.PartialViewContextImpl.renderState(PartialViewContextImpl.java:486) [jsf-impl-2.2.5-jbossorg-3.jar:]
        at com.sun.faces.context.PartialViewContextImpl.processPartial(PartialViewContextImpl.java:328) [jsf-impl-2.2.5-jbossorg-3.jar:]
        at javax.faces.context.PartialViewContextWrapper.processPartial(PartialViewContextWrapper.java:219) [jboss-jsf-api_2.2_spec-2.2.5.jar:2.2.5]
        at org.primefaces.context.PrimePartialViewContext.processPartial(PrimePartialViewContext.java:57) [primefaces-4.0.jar:4.0]
        at org.richfaces.context.ExtendedPartialViewContextImpl.processPartial(ExtendedPartialViewContextImpl.java:218) [richfaces-core-impl-4.3.5.Final.jar:4.3.5.Final]
        at javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot.encodeChildren(UIViewRoot.java:1004) [jboss-jsf-api_2.2_spec-2.2.5.jar:2.2.5]
        at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:1856) [jboss-jsf-api_2.2_spec-2.2.5.jar:2.2.5]
        at com.sun.faces.application.view.FaceletViewHandlingStrategy.renderView(FaceletViewHandlingStrategy.java:435) [jsf-impl-2.2.5-jbossorg-3.jar:]
        at com.sun.faces.application.view.MultiViewHandler.renderView(MultiViewHandler.java:133) [jsf-impl-2.2.5-jbossorg-3.jar:]
        at javax.faces.application.ViewHandlerWrapper.renderView(ViewHandlerWrapper.java:337) [jboss-jsf-api_2.2_spec-2.2.5.jar:2.2.5]
        at javax.faces.application.ViewHandlerWrapper.renderView(ViewHandlerWrapper.java:337) [jboss-jsf-api_2.2_spec-2.2.5.jar:2.2.5]
        at javax.faces.application.ViewHandlerWrapper.renderView(ViewHandlerWrapper.java:337) [jboss-jsf-api_2.2_spec-2.2.5.jar:2.2.5]
        at javax.faces.application.ViewHandlerWrapper.renderView(ViewHandlerWrapper.java:337) [jboss-jsf-api_2.2_spec-2.2.5.jar:2.2.5]
        at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.RenderResponsePhase.execute(RenderResponsePhase.java:120) [jsf-impl-2.2.5-jbossorg-3.jar:]
        at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.doPhase(Phase.java:101) [jsf-impl-2.2.5-jbossorg-3.jar:]
        at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.render(LifecycleImpl.java:219) [jsf-impl-2.2.5-jbossorg-3.jar:]
        at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:647) [jboss-jsf-api_2.2_spec-2.2.5.jar:2.2.5]
        at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletHandler.handleRequest(ServletHandler.java:85) [undertow-servlet-1.0.0.Final.jar:1.0.0.Final]
        at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterHandler.java:130) [undertow-servlet-1.0.0.Final.jar:1.0.0.Final]
        at org.apache.shiro.web.servlet.AbstractShiroFilter.executeChain(AbstractShiroFilter.java:449) [shiro-web-1.2.2.jar:1.2.2]
        at org.apache.shiro.web.servlet.AbstractShiroFilter$1.call(AbstractShiroFilter.java:365) [shiro-web-1.2.2.jar:1.2.2]
        at org.apache.shiro.subject.support.SubjectCallable.doCall(SubjectCallable.java:90) [shiro-core-1.2.2.jar:1.2.2]
        at org.apache.shiro.subject.support.SubjectCallable.call(SubjectCallable.java:83) [shiro-core-1.2.2.jar:1.2.2]
        at org.apache.shiro.subject.support.DelegatingSubject.execute(DelegatingSubject.java:383) [shiro-core-1.2.2.jar:1.2.2]
        at org.apache.shiro.web.servlet.AbstractShiroFilter.doFilterInternal(AbstractShiroFilter.java:362) [shiro-web-1.2.2.jar:1.2.2]
        at org.apache.shiro.web.servlet.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:125) [shiro-web-1.2.2.jar:1.2.2]
        at io.undertow.servlet.core.ManagedFilter.doFilter(ManagedFilter.java:56) [undertow-servlet-1.0.0.Final.jar:1.0.0.Final]
        at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterHandler.java:132) [undertow-servlet-1.0.0.Final.jar:1.0.0.Final]
        at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler.handleRequest(FilterHandler.java:85) [undertow-servlet-1.0.0.Final.jar:1.0.0.Final]
        at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletSecurityRoleHandler.handleRequest(ServletSecurityRoleHandler.java:61) [undertow-servlet-1.0.0.Final.jar:1.0.0.Final]
        at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletDispatchingHandler.handleRequest(ServletDispatchingHandler.java:36) [undertow-servlet-1.0.0.Final.jar:1.0.0.Final]
        at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.security.SecurityContextAssociationHandler.handleRequest(SecurityContextAssociationHandler.java:78)
        at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:25) [undertow-core-1.0.0.Final.jar:1.0.0.Final]
        at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.SSLInformationAssociationHandler.handleRequest(SSLInformationAssociationHandler.java:113) [undertow-servlet-1.0.0.Final.jar:1.0.0.Final]
        at io.undertow.security.handlers.AuthenticationCallHandler.handleRequest(AuthenticationCallHandler.java:52) [undertow-core-1.0.0.Final.jar:1.0.0.Final]
        at io.undertow.security.handlers.AbstractConfidentialityHandler.handleRequest(AbstractConfidentialityHandler.java:45) [undertow-core-1.0.0.Final.jar:1.0.0.Final]
        at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletConfidentialityConstraintHandler.handleRequest(ServletConfidentialityConstraintHandler.java:61) [undertow-servlet-1.0.0.Final.jar:1.0.0.Final]
        at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.CachedAuthenticatedSessionHandler.handleRequest(CachedAuthenticatedSessionHandler.java:70) [undertow-servlet-1.0.0.Final.jar:1.0.0.Final]
        at io.undertow.security.handlers.SecurityInitialHandler.handleRequest(SecurityInitialHandler.java:76) [undertow-core-1.0.0.Final.jar:1.0.0.Final]
        at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:25) [undertow-core-1.0.0.Final.jar:1.0.0.Final]
        at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.security.jacc.JACCContextIdHandler.handleRequest(JACCContextIdHandler.java:61)
        at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:25) [undertow-core-1.0.0.Final.jar:1.0.0.Final]
        at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:25) [undertow-core-1.0.0.Final.jar:1.0.0.Final]
        at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.handleFirstRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:240) [undertow-servlet-1.0.0.Final.jar:1.0.0.Final]
        at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.dispatchRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:227) [undertow-servlet-1.0.0.Final.jar:1.0.0.Final]
        at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.access$000(ServletInitialHandler.java:73) [undertow-servlet-1.0.0.Final.jar:1.0.0.Final]
        at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler$1.handleRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:146) [undertow-servlet-1.0.0.Final.jar:1.0.0.Final]
        at io.undertow.server.Connectors.executeRootHandler(Connectors.java:168) [undertow-core-1.0.0.Final.jar:1.0.0.Final]
        at io.undertow.server.HttpServerExchange$1.run(HttpServerExchange.java:687) [undertow-core-1.0.0.Final.jar:1.0.0.Final]
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145) [rt.jar:1.7.0_45]
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615) [rt.jar:1.7.0_45]
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744) [rt.jar:1.7.0_45]
Caused by: javax.el.PropertyNotFoundException: The class 'at.co.xss.Type2' does not have the property 'type1OnlyMethod'.
        at javax.el.BeanELResolver.getBeanProperty(BeanELResolver.java:730) [javax.el-3.0.0.jar:3.0.0]
        at javax.el.BeanELResolver.getValue(BeanELResolver.java:351) [javax.el-3.0.0.jar:3.0.0]
        at com.sun.faces.el.DemuxCompositeELResolver._getValue(DemuxCompositeELResolver.java:176) [jsf-impl-2.2.5-jbossorg-3.jar:]
        at com.sun.faces.el.DemuxCompositeELResolver.getValue(DemuxCompositeELResolver.java:203) [jsf-impl-2.2.5-jbossorg-3.jar:]
        at com.sun.el.parser.AstValue.getValue(AstValue.java:140) [javax.el-3.0.0.jar:3.0.0]
        at com.sun.el.parser.AstValue.getValue(AstValue.java:204) [javax.el-3.0.0.jar:3.0.0]
        at com.sun.el.ValueExpressionImpl.getValue(ValueExpressionImpl.java:226) [javax.el-3.0.0.jar:3.0.0]
        at org.jboss.weld.el.WeldValueExpression.getValue(WeldValueExpression.java:50) [weld-core-impl-2.1.2.Final.jar:2014-01-09 09:23]
        at org.jboss.weld.el.WeldValueExpression.getValue(WeldValueExpression.java:50) [weld-core-impl-2.1.2.Final.jar:2014-01-09 09:23]
        at com.sun.faces.facelets.el.TagValueExpression.getValue(TagValueExpression.java:109) [jsf-impl-2.2.5-jbossorg-3.jar:]
        ... 66 more
```

It seems that in the render-response phase the nested `ui:repeat` is "executed" for the currently deleted `Type2` object.

If I remove the second (nested) `ui:repeat` and add some plain `h:outputText` to access the property which is only available in `Type1`, everything works again without exception when I add or remove elements:

```
<h:form id="dummyForm">
  <ui:repeat value="#{dummyBean.objects}" var="_obj" >
    <!-- ... -->
    <h:panelGroup rendered="#{_obj.type eq '1'}">
      <h:outputText value="#{_obj.type1OnlyMethod.size()}" />
    </h:panelGroup>
    <!-- ... -->
</h:form>
```

Does anyone have any idea on this topic?

(Running on JEE7 application server (Wildfly 8.0.0.Final))

Answer (score 3):

This is caused by a bug in state management of Mojarra's `<ui:repeat>` which is fixed as per [issue 3215](https://java.net/jira/browse/JAVASERVERFACES-3215) as reported by my fellow Arjan Tijms. We also faced this problem when iterating over different `Block` instances at [zeef.com](https://zeef.com) (`LinkBlock`, `ImageBlock`, `TextBlock` and `FeedBlock`). The fix is available in [Mojarra 2.2.7](http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/glassfish/javax.faces/2.2.7/) and for JSF 2.0/2.1 backported to [Mojarra 2.1.29](http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/glassfish/javax.faces/2.1.29/) as per [issue 3221](https://java.net/jira/browse/JAVASERVERFACES-3221). So upgrading to at least that version (or just the latest available as per [Mojarra homepage](http://javaserverfaces.java.net/)) should do it.

Otherwise, your best bet is to replace `<ui:repeat>` by `<c:forEach>`.

Answer (score 1):

In my case I didn't had the option to upgrade Mojarra's version and to avoid c:forEach (that causes many side-effects when used with ui optionally rendered components) I replaced ui:repeat with a p:dataList and it worked. You'll have to do some CSS styling to hide the bullets but I think it's worth the price. I hope it helps someone ;)