# How to cast an object in jsf?

Tags: jsf, primefaces

I have an object `x`, which can have one `Parameter`. A `Parameter` is either a `ParaA` or a `ParaB`.

```
public abstract class Parameter {

    private final String displayPage;

    public Parameter(String displayPage) {
        this.displayPage= displayPage;
    }
}

public class ParaA extends Parameter {
    private List<String> strings;
    private String currentString;
}

public class ParaB extends Parameter {
    private int min;
    private int max;
}
```

I want to display each type of `Parameter` in a different way, so I use `<ui:include src="#{bean.parameter.displayPage}" />` to determine the `.xhtml` of each type of `Parameter`.

For example the `paraA_displayPage.xhtml` looks like this:

```
    <h:outputText value="ParaA" />
    <p:dataTable var="s" value="#{bean.parameter.strings}">
            <p:column>
                    <h:outputText value="#{s}" />
            </p:column>
    </p:dataTable>
```

This obviously doesn't work, because I have to cast `Parameter` to `ParaA`. So how can I manage this casting stuff in `jsf`?

I could use something ugly like this, as recommended here:
https://community.oracle.com/thread/1731149?start=0&tstart=0 but there is probably a better way.

```
public abstract class Parameter {
    public ParaA getParaA() {
        return (ParaA) this;
    }
    public ParaB getParaB() {
        return (ParaB) this;
    }
}
```

Comment: to check the type .Could it work in a EL expression?

Comment: Paul, *"This obviously doesn't work, because I have to cast Parameter to ParaA."* that's your own assumption. And it's incorrect. EL has no notion of strong typing.

Comment: "This obviously doesn't work, because I have to cast Parameter to ParaA" - are you sure? JSF uses reflection so it should work if the objects are correctly used.

Comment: @Smutje: that's EL, not JSF.

Comment: Paul, I guess you concretely got a `PropertyNotFoundException` when you said "obviously doesn't work". Is this true? In that case, is this helpful? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22613193/javax-el-propertynotfoundexception-when-submitting-uirepeat-with-conditionally/ In a future question better tell the facts not the assumptions :)

Comment: You guys are right, I don't have to cast. There was an other problem in my code, but I certainly thought the problem was caused because I didn't cast the object. Thanks for pointing this out. I still have a lot to learn.