# rendered attribute not evaluated in include

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, uiinclude, rendered-attribute

I have a include file with a parameter *bean* which I use for two concrete java *BeanA* and *BeanB* classes.

*BeanB* class has additional methods and therefore I check the render attribute to not access a method not available:

**View:**

```
<ui:include src="/inc_bean.xhtml">
    <ui:param name="bean" value="#{beanB}"/>
</ui:include>
```

**Include File with var `bean`:**

```
<p:tabView>
    <p:tab>
        <!-- content shall only be rendered if instance of BeanB -->
        <h:panelGroup rendered="#{bean.class.simpleName eq 'BeanB'}">
            <h:form>
                <h:inputText value="#{bean.propertyB}"/>
            </h:form>
        </h:panelGroup>
    </p:tab>
</p:tabView>
```

When I use the include with class *BeanA* I get following error at glassfish 4.1.1 and JSF mojarra 2.2.9:

> The class 'BeanA' does not have the property 'propertyB'.

**Workaround:**

wrap the inner content in a new strongly typed (*BeanB*) composite.

**Include File:**

```
<p:tabView>
    <p:tab>
        <comp:beanB bean="#{bean}" rendered="#{bean.class.simpleName eq 'BeanB'}"/>
    </p:tab>
</p:tabView>
```

Comment: That can happen if this is placed inside an `<ui:repeat>`. Is this true?

Comment: Not directly. It is within a primefaces `p:tabView`.

Comment: And `#{bean}` represents its `var`? The `<ui:repeat>` has this bug solved since 2.2.7, see also http://stackoverflow.com/q/22613193

Comment: it is a variable of the include file. I edited my question with further markup.

Comment: Do you have a stack trace at hand? `rendered='false'` usually is respected by the HTML code renderer and the `decode` method of input fields, but maybe something else tries to evaluate the expression.